# Javascript: Having Trouble Understanding Empty Initializer in Reduce Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce, initializer

Stared at this one for at least 4 hours before finally deciding to reach out to you experts.

New to JS. The goal of this practice exercise was to create an object from some given key-value pairs. I did it one way which worked, however, I'm having a hard time understanding this sample solution provided:

```
const object_From_Pairs = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => 
  ((a[v[0]] = v[1]), a), {});
console.log(object_From_Pairs([['Title', 'Oliver Twist'], ['Author', 'Charles Dickens']]));
// Output: {Title: "Oliver Twist", Author: "Charles Dickens"}
```

I understand how to use the `reduce` function, but I'm getting confused about what happens when you pass through an empty initializer value like `{}` or `[]`.

According to the [MDN web docs on the reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), the first time you go through the loop, your accumulator will be the initializer value that you can optionally provide (after the comma), and your value will be the value of the first item in the array you're passing through.

If that line of thinking is correct, it seems that my initial `a` value would be `{}`, and my `v` value would be the first subarray in the array, so `['Title', 'Oliver Twist']`. However, when I tried going through the steps like that, my results weren't making sense. My train of thought went something like this:

```
arr.reduce((a, v) => ((a[v[0]] = v[1]), a), {})
```

1. `a` = `{}` and `v` = `['Title', 'Oliver Twist']`
2. Replacing the a's and v's in the expression, we would have:

   arr.reduce((a, v) =>
   (({}[['Title', 'Oliver Twist'][0]] = ['Title', 'Oliver Twist'][1]), {}), {})
3. The `[0]` index value of `v` is `'Title'`, and the `[1]` index value of `v` is `'Oliver Twist'`, so we could shorten the expression to:

   arr.reduce((a, v) =>
   (({}Title = Oliver Twist), {}), {})
4. Here is where I start to get confused, because then after running through the `reduce` function the first time, it seems my new accumulator or `a` value would be `({}Title = Oliver Twist), {})`, and that doesn't make sense when I try to substitute it into `a` the second time around.

What am I missing? Is `{}` not the initializer? Does `{}` just tell it to surround the resulting answer in the `{}`? Having trouble understanding how this formats into an object with the `key: value` pairs so nicely!

Comment: The {} isn't really an initializer, its the just object you're starting with. You're passing the {} as the initial value of a, in your case. So the first time, your reducer function would receive a = {}, and would set a[v[0]] = v[1], or a["Title"] = "Oliver Twist". The same thing would happen for every item in arr, but each time a would be the object that was edited last time - so on the second run of your reducer function, a would equal {Title: 'Oliver Twist'}. The empty object {} isn't an initializer, its an initial value. Does that make sense?

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you for explaining it more simply for me!

Comment: The only part you miss is how JS evaluates comma separated expressions. Read more about [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: Yes, luckily I got that from another answer, so putting that together with the above comment, I was able to understand what is going on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `reduce` there is doing something slightly more complicated. It's not only assigning to a property of the `a`, the accumulator, it's also *returning* the accumulator. This code:

```
const object_From_Pairs = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => 
  ((a[v[0]] = v[1]), a), {});
```

is equivalent to:

```
const object_From_Pairs = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => {
  a[v[0]] = v[1];
  return a;
}, {});
```

which is equivalent to

```
const object_From_Pairs = arr => {
  const a = {};
  arr.forEach((v) => {
    a[v[0]] = v[1];
    // there's no need to do anything with a here
    // since the a you want to refer to is already in the outer scope
  });
};
```

The empty object is the initial value of the accumulator, which gets a property assigned to it on each iteration. The object does not stay empty.

> it seems my new accumulator or a value would be `({}Title = Oliver Twist), {})`

That's not valid syntax. On the second iteration, the value of `a` is

```
{ Title: 'Oliver Twist' }
```

so the callback that runs:

```
((a[v[0]] = v[1]), a)
```

is like

```
let a = { Title: 'Oliver Twist' };
return ((a[v[0]] = v[1]), a)
```

or, without the confusing comma operator:

```
let a = { Title: 'Oliver Twist' };
a[v[0]] = v[1];
return a;
```

Even better, I'd highly recommend avoiding `.reduce` in situations like these - it's just [not all that appropriate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) when the accumulator is the same value every time IMO. Use an ordinary loop instead. `arr.forEach` or `for (const subarr of arr)`.

For this particular situation, there's an even better option, to allow for the transformation of an array of key-value subarrays into a single object:

```js
const object_From_Pairs = Object.fromEntries;
console.log(object_From_Pairs([['Title', 'Oliver Twist'], ['Author', 'Charles Dickens']]));
// Output: {Title: "Oliver Twist", Author: "Charles Dickens"}
```

Done :)

Comment: _“which is equivalent to \[…\]”_ — except `return a;` must be outside the `forEach`. The original `object_From_Pairs` _returns_ the accumulator (from `reduce`), but the `forEach` version still doesn’t (even though the accumulator’s mutated).

Comment: THIS IS WHAT I NEEDED, THANK YOU!! I believe this is the second time you have saved my butt this week, @CertainPerformance >_<. When you broke it down to const a = {}, and explained that the ",a" just means "return a", it all clicked. And for what it's worth, your suggested solution is exactly how I did it on my own :). This sample solution they provided is much more convoluted!

Answer (score 0):

Answered! My main confusion was in not realizing that the `,a` part of the expression is actually shorthand for `return a`. I kept trying to insert the value of `a` into that spot again, which is why my results kept returning some strange invalid syntax.

My original line of code,

```
const object_From_Pairs = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => 
  ((a[v[0]] = v[1]), a), {});
```

Can be rewritten like this:

```
const object_From_Pairs = arr => arr.reduce((a, v) => {
  a[v[0]] = v[1];
  return a;
}, {});
```

Also, clarified that `{}` is the initial value we are passing through to `a`.

Much thanks to @[Certain Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) for the thorough answer!